Add trendline equation and R2 value
I have plotted the variation of concentration with time for a particular chemical. I needed to show the expotential trendline for the data. The data was filtered fom a larger dataset. I used the below code to obtain the trendlines but I am unable to add the equations and r2 value. any help will be appreciated.
dinotefuran <- filter(correlation_analysis,
                      chemical == "Dinotefuran")

dosage <- c("Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single",
            "Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double",
            "Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single",
            "Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double",
            "Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single",
            "Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double")

dinotefuran <- data.frame(dinotefuran, dosage)


Plot the variation of concentration in different matrices for Dinotefuran
ggplot(data = dinotefuran) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = time_das, y = concentration_mg_by_kg, color = dosage)) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = time_das, y = concentration_mg_by_kg, color = dosage, group = dosage),
              method = "nlsLM",
              formula = y ~ a * exp(b * x),
              se = FALSE,
              linetype = 2,
              method.args = list(start = c(a = 0.5, b = 0.2), control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 100))) +
  facet_wrap(~ plant_part, scales = "free") +
  labs(title = "Dinotefuran Variation in Plant parts",
       x = "Time (d)",
       y = "Concentration (mg/kg)") +
  design

This is the output I am getting currently
I tried nls method but it didnt give me the trendlines. I also want to display the confidence interval but when i change se=TRUE the trendlines are not diplayed. For the equations i tried using geom_text and stat_poly_eq but unfortunately neither of those worked.
The data:
correlation_analysis <- structure(list(
  chemical = c("Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran"),
  crop = c("Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper"),
  plant_part = c("Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)"),
  time_das = c(0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25),
  concentration_mg_by_kg = c(0.605, 0.547, 0.396, 0.176, 0.062, 0.029, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 1.148, 1.503, 0.765, 0.342, 0.096, 0.061, 0.015, 0.01, 0.01, 0.529, 0.407, 0.229, 0.094, 0.041, 0.01, 0.818, 0.592, 0.232, 0.089, 0.029, 0.01, 1.628, 1.519, 1.113, 0.517, 0.185, 0.096, 0.027, 0.01, 0.01, 2.32, 2.163, 1.624, 0.946, 0.356, 0.198, 0.058, 0.019, 0.01),
  type_of_obs = c("Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean"),
  dosage = c("Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double")
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L))


Can you include your data so that we can reproduce your graphs? You can use dput(dinotefuran) and share the output here.

@Eonema i have updated the data. Please check it out.

A possible option is to fit the model outside of ggplot, capture the various pieces (i.e. fitted values, R2, coefficients), then plot:
library(tidyverse)
library(minpack.lm)

correlation_analysis <- structure(list(
  chemical = c("Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran", "Dinotefuran"),
  crop = c("Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper", "Chilli pepper"),
  plant_part = c("Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)", "Fruit (dried)"),
  time_das = c(0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25),
  concentration_mg_by_kg = c(0.605, 0.547, 0.396, 0.176, 0.062, 0.029, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 1.148, 1.503, 0.765, 0.342, 0.096, 0.061, 0.015, 0.01, 0.01, 0.529, 0.407, 0.229, 0.094, 0.041, 0.01, 0.818, 0.592, 0.232, 0.089, 0.029, 0.01, 1.628, 1.519, 1.113, 0.517, 0.185, 0.096, 0.027, 0.01, 0.01, 2.32, 2.163, 1.624, 0.946, 0.356, 0.198, 0.058, 0.019, 0.01),
  type_of_obs = c("Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean", "Mean"),
  dosage = c("Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double", "Double")
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L))

dinotefuran <- filter(correlation_analysis,
                      chemical == "Dinotefuran")

dosage <- c("Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single",
            "Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double",
            "Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single",
            "Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double",
            "Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single","Single",
            "Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double","Double")

dinotefuran <- data.frame(dinotefuran, dosage)

# Create model function
mod_nlslm <- \(data) nlsLM(
  formula = concentration_mg_by_kg ~ a * exp(b * time_das),
  start = list(a = 0.12345, b = 0.54321), data = data,
  algorithm = "LM", control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 100)
)

# Model outside of ggplot augmenting data with R2 and fitted points
modelled_df <- dinotefuran |> 
  nest(data = -c(plant_part, dosage)) |> 
  mutate(
    model = map(data, mod_nlslm),
    r2 = map2_dbl(model, data, modelr::rsquare),
    fitted = map(model, fitted),
    coef = map(model, coef),
    coef_a = map(coef, 1),
    coef_b = map(coef, 2)
    ) |> 
  unnest(c(data, fitted))

# Summarise labels & positioning
label_df <- modelled_df |> 
  summarise(r2 = paste("R2=", round(first(r2), 2)), 
            a = paste("a=", round(first(coef_a), 2)),
            b = paste("b=", round(first(coef_b), 2)),
            x = mean(time_das),
            y = max(concentration_mg_by_kg),
            .by = c(plant_part, dosage))

# Plot R2 and fitted lines with original data
modelled_df |>
  ggplot(aes(time_das, concentration_mg_by_kg, color = dosage, group = dosage)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = fitted), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = paste(r2, "\n", a, ",", b)), 
            data = label_df) +
  facet_wrap(~plant_part, scales = "free") +
  labs(
    title = "Dinotefuran Variation in Plant parts",
    x = "Time (d)",
    y = "Concentration (mg/kg)"
  )


Created on 2024-05-07 with reprex v2.1.0

I did try stat_regline_equation. Even though it displays the equation and r2 values, they both seem wrong. The equation I am looking for should be in the form y=ae^bx. Also, when I tried to visualise this in Excel, the r2 value was very close to 1.

Is this close to what you want? I can look to add the equation.

Great. Added the coefficients. You may want to adjust the formatting :)
